# Socket.connect hangs indefinitely on Android 11, Samsung Galaxy A52s when connecting to alexanderweinert.net

Tags: java, android, network-programming, samsung-galaxy

I am trying to connect to my domain from an Android app on my Samsung Galaxy A52s (Model Number: SM-A528B/DS) running on Android 11. The domain is managed by `namecheap.com` and points to a server hosted by Hetzner. The relevant code snippets are as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.net.SocketFactory;
```

```
try {
    final Socket socket = SocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket();
    final InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress("alexanderweinert.net", 443);
    final int timeout = 2000;
    socket.connect(remoteAddress, timeout);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Debugging shows that the call to `socket.connect` times out after two seconds. Connecting the same socket to, e.g., `google.com` works as expected. Increasing the timeout does not change the behavior, neither does attempting to connect to port 80 instead of 443. The behavior does not occur in the emulator, but only on actual hardware.

What might be causing this? The behavior occurs both using my local WiFi as well as mobile data, so I am currently ruling out misconfiguration of my local network as the cause. I'd be happy to provide people with a minimal app showcasing the behavior.

### Answers to Comments

- I have not been able to test any Android version other than 11
- According to debugging information, the domain name is resolved to the correct IP

Comment: Is it Android 11 or the device? Did you try below 11?

Comment: Is domain name converted to an ip correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your questions @blackapps, I've added the answers to them to the question

Comment: Hi @AlexanderWeinert, any solution to this? Even I am facing this issue.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderWeinert, any solution to this? Even I am facing this issue.